# Adding 2 monitors to a laptop with only 1 video output

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I recently bought a new Laptop (Asus Vivo Book X413FA). It offers 1 x HDMI as well as a USB-C connector. I've just found out though that the USB-C connector does not support video out, subsequently meaning that I can't use it to add a 2nd monitor. (The first monitor being connected via the 1 HDMI port).

Is there any way (or device) I can implement to have 2 monitors with extended display set up?
Can the USB-C that doesn't support video, be somehow converted to support video?
Is there any HDMI splitter that will extend to 2 displays but utilising only 1 HDMI port on the laptop?

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a Docking Station for your laptop that supports more monitors. Try a USB connected docking station.

Comment: Are you sure your video chipset is up to the task? Video output require CPU/GPU processing and enough RAM for all buffers etc. If the chipset can handle it, then it may be possible. Check with your manufacturer. A USB solution may be possible, but it depends on your USB chipset hardware etc.

Comment: Google says they have USB 3.1 Gen 1 - which as far as I'm aware cannot carry video.

Answer (score 0):

Second question first...

> Can the USB-C that doesn't support video, be
> somehow converted to support video?

Yes.  There is a company called DisplayLink that offers USB-to-video chips for situations like this.  These are not high performance gaming chips, but they work fine for general web surfing and office productivity stuff.  I believe that DisplayLink only makes the chips, the adapters and docks that use these chips are available from a number of manufacturers.  This is like adding another video card to the computer, which takes me to your first question...

> Is there any way (or device) I can implement to have 2 monitors with
> extended display set up?

When adding two displays to two video controllers the desktop acts different than with two displays on the same controller.  With one controller one display can know what the other is doing, allowing a window to span the gap separating the two.  With two controllers windows can't span this gap and dragging a window from one to the other is possible but it will "jump" from one to the other rather than just "slide" over smoothly.

> Is there any HDMI splitter that
> will extend to 2 displays but utilising only 1 HDMI port on the
> laptop?

I would guess someone makes these things.  That can't be cheap though.  While it would solve the problem of an extended desktop it doesn't add to the resolution the HDMI port can handle.  If the output supports 4K then splitting that to two 1080p screens would not be a problem.  If the output has a 1080p max then you'd be lucky to have two 720p screens.